# asp.net 5 dependency injection intercept call method

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am working with the new DIP (Dependency Injection) of asp.net 5 https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection.
So far I've done pretty well.

But now it's time to do more complex things. As I have done in the past with Windsor Castle or Unity.
I need to make a proxy to a class, to intercept calls and log it.

**AOP** (aspect oriented program)

In Windsord Castle it is called: DinamicProxy
In asp.net 5  how i can make the same?

For Example:

```
public interface ITracingInterceptorHelper
{
    void BeforeCall(string typeName, string methodName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters);
    void ErrorOnCall(string typeName, string methodName, Exception e);
    void AfterCall(string typeName, string methodName, object returnValue);
}


public class TracingInterceptor : BaseInterceptor, IInterceptor
    {
        private readonly ITracingInterceptorHelper _helper;

        public TracingInterceptor(ITracingInterceptorHelper tracingInterceptorHelper)
        {
            _helper = tracingInterceptorHelper;
        }


        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
        //...
        }
    }
```

Thanks. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In asp.net 5 how i can make the same?

You can't. This is not possible with the built-in container of ASP.NET 5. The built-in container is not suited for [any considerably sized application that follows the SOLID principles and apply AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681477/dependency-injection-in-the-asp-net-5-vnext/30682214#30682214).

You should especially not 'downgrade' to the built-in container if the container you are using is working fine for you.