# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Service Locator with Simple Injector returning null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, simple-injector

I have an .NET MVC 5 .NET Framework Application which I am converting to .NET Core 2.1

I have a custom action filter which in .NET Framework version was registered as a Global Filter in a Filterconfig class like below:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter());
    }
}
```

Within the custom action filter in the .NET version I was using Service Locator pattern (I know it can be considered an anti pattern) as below:

```
var myService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyService>();
```

I am using Simple Injector for DI and everything works fine in the .NET Version.  With the .NET Core version I am trying to get the same functionality working but myService is always null

I am still using Simple Injector (as all the other projects in the solution use it and they are not getting move to .NET Core projects (only the web one is).

My Startup.cs class has this code:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter());
});

SimpleInjectorConfig.IntegrateSimpleInjector(services, container);
```

At my service layer I have a SimpleInjector Registartion class that gets called from Web Layer - it then calls down to DAL Layer to do Registration

```
public class SimpleInjectorRegistration
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IMyService, MyService>();
        //further code removed for brevity
```

When I run the application with a breakpoint in the Custom Filter and a breakpoint in this RegisterServices method I can see the breakpoint in the RegisterServices method gets hit first and then the breakpoint in the Custom Filter - this made me think everything was wired up in the container correctly.

However I am trying to do the below again in the custom filter with .NET Core Service Locator pattern

```
var myService = filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>();
```

but the result is always null?

Is there something I have missed in this setup?

**------------  UPDATE -------------------**

Based on Stevens comment I added a constructor to my action filter and passed in the Simple Injector container.

So My Startup class now is:

```
public class Startup
{
    //Simple Injector container
    private Container container = new Container(); 

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();


        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
           options.Filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter(container));
```

My Custom filter now is like below with constructor added:

```
public class MyCustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public MyCustomActionFilter(Container container)
    {
        _myService = container.GetService<IMyService>();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       //actual code of custom filter removed - use of MyService
```

I set a breakpoint on the Constructor of MyCustomActionFilter and I can see it getting hit but I get an Error thrown:

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: 'The IDbContext is registered as 'Async Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Async Scoped) scope.'

MyService has a Dependency on the DbContext which is injected into it (it is doing work saving and retrieving data from DB.

For the DB Context I registered it as below:

```
public class SimpleInjectorRegistration
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container, string connectionString)
    {
        container.Register<IDbContext>(() => new MyDbContext(connectionString),
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }

}
```

Comment: share your filter code please!

Comment: `filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyService>()` resolves the service from tge ASP.NET Core configuration system, not from Simple Injector. You will have to inject the Simple Injector container into your filter and resolve from the container.

Comment: @Steven - is there any documentation I could read on Simple Injector on how I would inject the SI container into the custom filter - is it where I am newing it up in the options.filter.Add?

Comment: No, there is no specific documentation on this, but it would be as straightforeward as doing this: `options.Filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter(this.container));`

Comment: @Steven - yip got that wired up - It is failing with a different error now - should I raise a new question for that or will I Edit the Question here with the update and the new issue?

Comment: Feel free to update your question with the proper details. Do note that it might take a few hours before I am able to look at it. (even a developer needs some sleep sometimes)

Comment: @Steven - no problems :) - think I'm in a simlar Timezone to yourself (Ireland) so I need to pack away the laptop myself soon - basically its failing because the Service I am using to inject into the filter has the DBContext injected into it - and I marked it when registered as Lifestyle.Scoped - ill do some more experimenting myself and will add the Extra info to the question and then ill call it a night myself.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some significant changes between how to integrate Simple Injector in the old ASP.NET MVC and the new ASP.NET Core. In the old system, you would be able to replace the `IDependencyResolver`. ASP.NET Core, however, contains a completely different model, with its own internal DI Container. As it is [impossible](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) to replace that built-in container with Simple Injector, you will have the two containers run side-by-side. In that case the built-in container will resolve framework and third-party components, where Simple Injector will compose application components for you.

When you call `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService`, you will be requesting the built-in container for a service, *not* Simple Injector. Adding the `IMyService` registration to the built-in container, as TanvirArjel's answer suggests, might seem to work at first, but that completely skips Simple Injector from the equation, which is obviously not an option, as you wish to use Simple Injector as your application container.

To mimic the Service Locator-like behavior you had before, you will have to inject the `SimpleInjector.Container` into your filter, as follows:

```
options.Filters.Add(new MyCustomActionFilter(container));
```

It would be an error, however, to call the container from within the constructor, as you are showing in your question:

```
public class MyCustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public MyCustomActionFilter(Container container)
    {
        _myService = container.GetService<IMyService>(); // NEVER DO THIS!!!
    }

    ...
}
```

> **WARNING: You should *never* resolve from the container from the constructor. Or in more general: you should *never* use any injected dependency from inside the constructor. The constructor should only store the dependency.**

As Mark Seemann explained, [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). In this case, it even gets worse because:

- During the time that the constructor of `MyCustomActionFilter` is invoked, there is no active scope, and `IMyService` can't be resolved
- Even if `IMyService` could be resolved, `MyCustomActionFilter` is a `Singleton` and storing `IMyService` in a private field will cause a hidden [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). This could lead to all sorts of trouble.

Instead of storing the resolved, `IMyService` dependency, you should store the `Container` dependency:

```
public class MyCustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Container _container;

    public MyCustomActionFilter(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        myService = container.GetService<IMyService>();
        //actual code of custom filter removed - use of MyService 
    }
}
```

During the time that `OnActionExecuting` is called, there will be an active Simple Injector `Scope`, which will allows `IMyService` to be resolved. On top of that, as `IMyService` is not stored in a private field, it will not be cached and will not cause a Captive Dependency.

In your question you referred to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Whether or not the injection of the `Container` into your filter is in fact an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern depends on where the filter is located. As Mark Seemann [puts](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) it:

> A DI container encapsulated in a Composition Root is not a Service Locator - it's an infrastructure component.

In other words, as long as the filter class is located *inside* your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), you are not applying the Service Locator anti-pattern. This does mean, however, that you must make sure that the filter itself contains as little interesting behavior as possible. That behavior should all be moved to the service that the filter resolves.

Comment: I will give that a go.  Its probably objective but if I was developing a green field asp.net core application is there a use case for Simple Injector or any of the other DI Frameworks sitting beside the in-built .NET Core one?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681477/why-would-one-use-a-third-party-di-container-over-the-built-in-asp-net-core-di-c

Comment: Also note that I wrote a [complete book](https://manning.com/seemann2) about DI and it compares MS.DI in detail to Simple Injector and Autofac. It explains in detail where MS.DI falls short.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steven points out, the built-in container will resolve framework and third-party components, where Simple Injector will compose application components for you. For built-in container, it could not resolve the service from simple injector. For simple injector, you could try [EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#cross-wiring-asp-net-and-third-party-services) to resolve services from built-in container.

For `options.Filters.Add`, it also accepts `MyCustomActionFilter instance`, without resigering `Container` as depedence into `MyCustomActionFilter`, you could try register `MyCustomActionFilter` in sample injector, and then pass this instance to `options.Filters.Add`.

- Register Services

  ```
      private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
      // Add application presentation components:
      container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
      container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

      // Add application services. For instance:
      container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
      container.Register<MyCustomActionFilter>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
      // Allow Simple Injector to resolve services from ASP.NET Core.
      container.AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents(app);
  }
  ```
- add MyCustomActionFilter

  ```
          services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
      {
          using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
          {
              options.Filters.Add(container.GetRequiredService<MyCustomActionFilter>());
          }
      });
      #region SampleInjector
      IntegrateSimpleInjector(services);
      #endregion
  ```

  **Note** If you specify `container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();`, you will need `using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))` when you call `container.GetRequiredService<MyCustomActionFilter>()`.