# Why does .NET Core DI container not inject ILogger?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to get logging up and running in my C# console app based on .NET Core 2.1.

I added the following code to my DI declaration:

```
var sc = new ServiceCollection();

sc.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
    builder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning);
    builder.AddFilter("Program", LogLevel.Warning);
    builder.AddConsole();
    builder.AddEventLog();
});
```

I am trying to inject the service by using the Interface `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` in the constructor of the services, but I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'MyService'.

```
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateEnumerable(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
    at Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 27
```

Did I misunderstand something here? Shouldn't the `AddLogging` method be enough to expose the Service in the DI Container?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The dependency injection system doesn't register `ILogger`. Instead it registers `ILogger<T>`. If you need an instance of a logger, you will need to accept `ILogger<MyService>`.

The reason behind this is that the generic argument is used to build the logger's category name--something which all loggers require. With a non-generic logger there's not necessarily a good default name. If you *really* want a non-generic `ILogger`, you can register one like this (change the name as you please):

```
services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("DefaultLogger"));
```

Alternatively, you can accept an `ILoggerFactory` in your constructor and then create your own logger on the fly.

Comment: "With a non-generic logger there's not necessarily a good default name." That's not necessarily true, because in most cases the name is derived from the name of the consumer, which is what you achieve by injecting an `ILogger<MyService>` into `MyService`. Most DI Containers actually allow you to make such configuration (all except MS.DI). This practice is typically referred to as "context-based injection."

Comment: I meant with the MS based DI, which can't/doesn't  create a category name for the context

Answer (score 11):

In order for MS.DI to be able to do a mapping from `ILogger` to `ILogger<T>` where the `T` becomes the consumer, it must support context-based injection. This means that when building an application using MS.DI, you will have to let your classes depend on `ILogger<T>`.

There are multiple reasons why MS.DI lacks this feature. I think the two most important reasons are:

- **MS.DI only implements features that are required for framework components itself.** Remember: MS.DI was built and designed especially for the ASP.NET Core framework, its components, and its third-parties. Much less to be a fully fledged DI Container
- **MS.DI tries to be a lowest common denominator** (LCD) where it tries to only support features that all other DI Containers support as well to allow you to replace this built-in container with a more mature, feature-rich DI Container.

I understand your annoyance. It would be great to see MS.DI support context-based injection, because it makes a lot of sense to depend on `ILogger` instead for your application components, because **this makes your code simpler, easier to test, and less error prone.**

Unfortunately, because of MS.DI's design and its LCD philosophy, it's unlikely that it ever gets such feature. Every time Microsoft adds behavior, a long and complex discussion is started with maintainers of most DI Containers to see how such feature can be supported in a way that is compatible with all other libraries (I've been parted of many of these discussions myself). This is a daunting task, and already [proved](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/) to be impossible in some cases.

Instead, it makes sense to select a more mature and feature-rich DI Container that contains such feature, and many other features. For [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org), for instance, we  [added integration](https://simpleinjector.org/servicecollection+logging) for injecting `ILogger`. But there are other DI Containers that allow you to inject `ILogger`.